# Can IPhone 4 share WIFI over WIFI?

Tags: iphone, wifi, internet-sharing, tethering

I'm going to location where my 3G will be pretty expensive. Can I connect my iPhone 4 to WIFI in hotel and share it for my laptop thru WIFI as well? That way I could save some money to not have to buy 2 x WIFI from HOTEL.

Comment: You could connect your laptop and make it share its INTERNET

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. The iPhone can either act as a client or an Access Point, not both simultaneously.

If the WiFi access isn't registered against the device's MAC address then you should be able to use the login on either the iPhone or Laptop (but probably not at the same time).

If it is MAC address based registration then you could register with your iPhone and then change your Laptop's MAC address to match the iPhone's MAC address so that you only have to buy one WiFi access card.

Answer (score 1):

Since version 5.50.2 (4/4/2012), MyWi can share your wifi connection.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably much easier off the other way round: make sure your laptop has wifi, and enable internet sharing on your laptop, so that your iphone connects through your laptop to the internet.

I think this will require you to have an extra wifi card plugged into (or connected to) your laptop though (the build-in wifi would connect to the internet, the second wifi adapter would share its connection to other devices, like your iphone)

Comment: Same problem here, the Mac can't share its WiFi connection over the same WiFi device. The WAN connection would have to be provisioned by another network interface and then shared out over the WiFi.

Comment: I have new MacBook Air with i7 but don't have any spare wifi connections. But maybe I could use USB cable with my laptop and WIFI for getting internet thru iPHONE? I'm preety sure I would be using Iphone more with WIFI as it's easier to carry it all day long then Mac. So would prefer to get INET on IPHONE and share it with MAC.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can. Install MyWi 6 and go on!

Comment: Can you explain how this works and give a link

Answer (score 0):

TPLINK-MR3020 wifi repeater, wifi share modem 3G, AP, usb powered